# Nginx not applying gzip compression on CSS and JS with query string

Tags: css, regex, linux, wordpress, nginx

I am currently setting up my web server for my wordpress blog with Nginx on ubuntu 14.04, I've enabled the gzip compression but certain files are not compressed in fact, all my css and JS files with a query string are not compressed.

here is the pattern I am using "style.css?v=1.1.2" to version my css and JS

This is my configuration in my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

 gzip_vary on;
 gzip_proxied any;
 gzip_comp_level 6;
 gzip_buffers 16 8k;
 gzip_http_version 1.1;
 gzip_types text/plain text/css application/javascript text/xml application/xml+rss;
```

This is the regex I tried to use to match my files..

```
  location ~ \.(css|js|x?html?|php)($|\?.*$) {
    access_log off;
    expires 7d;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    }
```

some info for why my query strings are being ignored by Nginx will be great.

Comment: Why not to just try location without arguments? Nginx chooses the longest location to serve a request. Arguments can't be used as part of location. Try this: *(css|js|x?html?|php) {...}*